# Azure Function Host to give a Message in case of invalid URI path:

Tags: azure, azure-functions, postman, azure-function-app, azure-functions-runtime

**Azure Function Host to give a Message in case of invalid URI path:**

Hi, I'm using an Azure Function and testing it through Postman.

My requirement is, when we pass the invalid URI path but the correct Host... we are getting Status: 404 Not Found.

But is it possible and is there any way that we can get Status: 400 Bad Request with a message "Invalid URI Path".

**Sample Test Case:**

https://SampleFunction.azurewebsites.net/api/SampleFunction

When I try with this URL: [https://SampleFunction.azurewebsites.net/apia'a\'b"c>](https://SampleFunction.azurewebsites.net/apia%27a%5C%27b%22c%3E) I will be getting Status: 404 Not Found. But we are expecting Status:400 with a proper Message.

Please let me know if we can handle this through Azure Function Configurations/Azure Portal Settings.

Thanks in Advance...

Comment: Hi, may I know if the solution provided below helps your problem ? If still have any problem, please let me know.

Comment: Hi Hurt Shen, thanks a lot for your reply. I just tried this approach and now able to validate the URI path. And I'm just thinking about the Security part, due to proxy addition.... Will there be any impact to the existing function... And also will there be any loophole to access the proxy URL and access the function without going through the Azure AAD Authentication. Could you please help me with these details

Comment: You want the function go through Azure AD ?

Comment: The solution I provided below is just a sample, so the function is created in "Anonymous" level. You can configure your function with "Function" level, and then it will require a `code` query param when you request it. I think it will be more secure.

Comment: And for your concern about impact to the existing function, I don't think it will impact other existing function. If you find any situation of impact other function, please let me know, I will help you to solve it.

Comment: yeah Sure Hury... I will be letting you know the future complications if any I come across. Thanks a lot once again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this requirement, you can do it by proxy. Please refer to my steps below:

**1.** I have created a function and its url is: `https://xxx.azurewebsites.net/api/SampleFunction`

**2.** Go to "**Proxies**" tab page of the function app and add a proxy like:

[image]

**3.** Add lines of code to your function:

[image]

**4.** After that, when you request the function url with `https://SampleFunction.azurewebsites.net/apia'a\'b"cxxxxxxx`, it will response `400`  with the message you specified.